# How can I use regex to select filenames that contain a certain string?

Tags: python, regex

I need to iterate over files and select those that **end with** `_FirstPerson_04312.json` or `_Hybrid_04312.json`, where `04312` can be any sequence of digits 0-9.
I haven't used regex much so far, can someone help me how to do this?
Thanks!

my code so far:

```
for fname in os.listdir(path=search_path):
   if fname.endswith(".json"):
      # if fname contains -- regex
```

Comment: You don't have to regex. You can split the file based on underscore. Like: fname.split("_")

Comment: @VRComp Yeah, but then you need to match "any sequence of digits 0-9", which is easier in regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can match both json ending and number pattern in one go with the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) package:

```
import re

for fname in os.listdir(path=search_path):
    if re.match(".*?_(?:FirstPerson|Hybrid)_\d+\.json", fname):
        # ...
```

Comment: I'd also recommend adding the end-of-string marker, `$`, so that you don't match, say, `.json.tar.gz` or something. Then you could also use `re.search` and remove the `.*?`.

Comment: Is there a point to using an anonymous group for the regex? I guess it saves a few cpu cycles because the regex engine doesn't need to bother storing match1 anywhere

Comment: @JakobLovern hi I am interested - can you write the pattern you would use?

Comment: Basically the same pattern, just `.*?_(FirstPerson|Hybrid)_\d+\.json`. This creates a capture group instead of an anonymous group.

Answer (score 0):

You can fairly easy check the regex with https://regex101.com

```
import re

result = []

files = ["ffdf_FirstPerson_04312.json", "ffff_Hybrid_04312.json", "ajaxamsterdam.json"]
for fname in files:
    if fname.endswith(".json"):
        x = re.findall('_FirstPerson_\d*.json|_Hybrid_\d*.json', fname)
        if x:
            result.append(fname)
```

Comment: Why `findall` instead of `search`?

Comment: `fname.endswith(".json")` is redundant

Comment: yeah, search is better (faster, I guess).

Comment: Why `\d*` instead of `\d+`?

Comment: You can simplify the OR expression: `_(FirstPerson|Hybrid)_`

Comment: I'm thinking about semantics more than performance. There should be at most one match, so why get a list?

Comment: BTW, if you plug everything in on regex101, you can save it and get a permalink. [Here's one](https://regex101.com/r/VHsuRr/1)

Comment: I don't want to annoy anyone, just thought I can do this so let's try to help. That's all. It works, but you're right the code can be better.